# Js error: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, express, post

I'm having the error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` on try to post refs to my dedicated express server, can you guys help me?

```
function create() {

    event.preventDefault()

    firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value
    lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value
    username = document.getElementById('username').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value

    const userInfo = {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        username: username, 
        password: password
    }

    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "no-cors",
        body: {userInfo},
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
    }

    fetch('https://marcelochat.herokuapp.com/create', config)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp)
    })
}
```

The error is here: `.then(res => res.json())`
NOTE: the firstName, lastName, username and password consts are the input values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value
    lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value
    username = document.getElementById('username').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value
```

Is this variables out of scope?

if not, try this

```
  let  firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value
  let  lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value
  let  username = document.getElementById('username').value
  let  password = document.getElementById('password').value
```

and should config.body userInfo be inside the object?